# Pick dictionary keys:values randomly

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to randomly pick 1000 dictionary key, value pairs whose values is 'Zero'.

The dictionary keys are in alphabetic order at the moment. It has thousands of entries, below is part of it

```
[('2014','Zero'),
('2015','Zero'),
('2016','Zero')
('2017','NotZero')]
```

I successfully pick up 1000 'Zero' entries.

```
Zero = []
cnt = 0
for j in range(len(DIC)):
    if list(DIC.values())[j] == 'Zero':
        Zero.append(list(DIC.items()))
    cnt += 1
    if cnt == 1000:
        break
```

But I cannot find a way to randomize them. It's bias to pick the first 1000 lines because they are in alphabetic order.

Any suggestions on solving this problem?  Thank you!

Comment: Without getting any more context, it seems like it would be much more efficient to have `'Zero'` and `'NotZero'` as the keys, and the values as lists.  Then all you have to do is `random.sample(DIC['Zero'], 1000)`. This of course depends on how many times you are going to access the values by their current keys (the year) and how many times you will want "1000 random years with the value of zero"

Comment: `[('2014','Zero'),
('2015','Zero'),
('2016','Zero')
('2017','NotZero')]` This is not a dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary does not allow for random access of elements without knowing their key. The only solution is to find all `Zero` elements, store them in a list, and then taking a random selection from them:

```
import random
zeros = [k for k, v in d.items() if v == "Zero"]
random.sample(zeros, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

It can easily be done with pandas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': dic.keys(), 'value': dic.values()})
zeros = df.loc[df.value == 'Zero']
sample = zeros.sample(1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `shuffle` function:

```
import random

# get your zero entries

random.shuffle(Zero)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to get all of the keys whose matching values are `Zero`, then use `random.sample()` to choose 1000 random entries.

```
import random

random_keys = random.sample(
    [key for (key, value) in dic.items() if value == 'Zero'],
    1000,
)
```